# Should I cut off black banana ending before eating?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, safety

I was always told that I should cut off the black ending of a banana before eating, because it would be dangerous. Sources for this claim can for example be found [here](http://girlshowtoimpress.com/youll-get-sick-if-you-wont-cut-off-a-black-ending-of-the-banana/) (though that source is actually rebuking the claim, but I was not able to find any other online sources). Is it indeed true that eating this black ending is unhealthy?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVRKE.jpg]
<sub>[Source of the image](http://www.szwed.hekko.pl/inne.htm)</sub>

Comment: Here's some [evidence that this is a 'notable claim'](http://girlshowtoimpress.com/youll-get-sick-if-you-wont-cut-off-a-black-ending-of-the-banana/) i.e. that you're not the only person who has been told that a black end of banana is dangerous.

Comment: What is the black end of a banana?

Comment: @flimzy: I assume it's the end opposite the stem, which is usually dark in color.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge AFAIK if you remove the skin, the banana is white on the all ends. Or is this a question about a practice of eating bananas with skin?

Comment: @Anixx If you remove the skin, the banana is not always perfectly white on the ends. This is not a question about a practice of eating bananas with skin.

Comment: I think I normally open the banana from the stem end and don't eat the black bit because it has a bad texture at least, and IIRC doesn't taste nice anyway.

Comment: You should open your bananas the other way around, it's much easier.

Comment: The answer to this could be the same as the answer to the citrus peel question. Fda says nothing therefore safe? Just a little boring.

Comment: Here's as far as I got: Banana *peel* browning [is caused by enzymes](http://kukr.lib.ku.ac.th/Fulltext_kukr/KU0296171c.pdf). I can't find a source for the *pulp* browning; perhaps it's the same? Bananas begin growing at that "black end", which could mean it consists of remnants of the flower. I was looking for a time-lapse video of a growing banana fruit to confirm this, but couldn't find one. Does anyone know a banana farmer?

Comment: @Anko tip rot is completely different and it's of fungal origin, see e.g. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02980350#page-1

Answer (score 3):

No, you needn't cut off the end of the banana unless it's rotten.

There are a two main reasons why bananas turn black.

1. Bananas keep on maturing even when they have been harvested. [This happens through enzymes and oxydation](http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/91/4/1436.short) and it's part of the normal life cycle of the fruit. In fact, a slightly over-ripe fruit is likely more nutritious because of higher sugar content. If your banana is simply ripening, you can eat it, it's oxidized and not rotten.

   > In ripening banana (Musa sp. [AAA group, Cavendish subgroup] cv Valery) fruit, the concentration of glycolytic intermediates increased in response to the rapid conversion of starch to sugars and CO<sub>2</sub>.
2. Fungi of the [Colletotrichum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colletotrichum) family (and in particular *Colletotrichum musae* is the banana-specific one) [are endemic on vegetables and cause rot.](http://www.idosi.org/wjas/wjas7(6)/17.pdf) One well known effect is tip rot in bananas. Probably these fungi are not particularly toxic (this is my assumption), but the normal "avoid rotten food" advice applies.